# Animated sliding divs on click button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a simple script that slides the next 'slide' div in on a button click, I have 3 divs all inline, left alligned. theyre all set to a width, on 'next' button click id like the next slide to slide in, ive made the following fiddle only I cant seem to get it working...

Can anybody see where im going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/x2qk7/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the positioning and the initial value of `left`. Try something like this:

```
.slide {width:788px;float:left;left:0;position:relative;}
```